# Connecting GetParameterAsText with Pick List?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters, multi-values, value-list

I am sitting here already awhile and can't find an answer on my own. 
I actually have pretty much the same Problem which was already asked ([MultiValue-String to SQL Expressions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229161/multivalue-string-to-sql-expressions?newreg=696602b5989043bd96fee53f7127f486)). 
But mine is more basic because of missing knowlegde. 
I tried to use the codechunk out of the other Problem but when i run it the expected Pick-List is always without Values. 
Some Basic Questions actually include missing comprehension of the functions.

```
multival = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # 'Store_1;Store_2;Store_3'
vals = multival.split(";")

where_stub = """"NAME" IN ({})"""
stores = ','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in vals])
where = where_stub.format(stores)
```

I actually don't know where the `multival`comes from and which Position its claimimg in the code. Maybe for a better understanding my task is to create a Route for a Pizza delivery with about 6 Stops. As data I got a file with 25 Stores which from I should pick various stores. To avoid a SQL-Expression I would like to have a Pick-List as in the other Problem shown ([MultiValue-String to SQL Expressions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229161/multivalue-string-to-sql-expressions?newreg=696602b5989043bd96fee53f7127f486)).

My Code looks like this

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#workspace =  GetParameterAsText (0) ???
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

# Local variables:
in_network_dataset = "Transportation/Streets_ND"
outNALayerName = "BestRoute"


# Process: Make Route Layer
arcpy.MakeRouteLayer_na(in_network_dataset, outNALayerName, "TravelTime", 
"FIND_BEST_ORDER", "PRESERVE_BOTH", "", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", 
"Oneway;RestrictedTurns", "", "", "", "")

# Process: Select
Stores = "Stores.shp"
Stores_Select = "Stores_Select_Output"
Expression = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
vals = Expression.split(";")

where_stub = """"NAME" IN ({})"""
stores = ','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in vals])
Expression = where_stub.format(stores)


arcpy.Select_analysis(Stores, Stores_Select, Expression)
```

It will execute until the select-process but then it does not make a difference between my script and a totaly empty one... 
Can Someone explain me how to get the Parameters into my Pick-List and maybe some Ground explanation so i understand what the Codechunk from ([MultiValue-String to SQL Expressions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229161/multivalue-string-to-sql-expressions?newreg=696602b5989043bd96fee53f7127f486)) includes?

This is how my Parameter Panel looks:

[image: Pic1]

Comment: Have you configured a tool dialog for your Python script tool?

Comment: If i understand that right you mean with tool dialog the actual outcoming tool?  This one would be empty an the Error000735 occures

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an "actual outcoming tool".  Please [edit] your question to describe how you right-clicked on a toolbox in the Catalog window and used Add Script to configure the Python script tool.  We'll need to see exactly what you did on the Parameters panel.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have your multivalue as the third parameter on your tool dialog but you are trying to reference it using an index value of 1:

```
multival = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

when it should be referenced using an index value of 2:

```
multival = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
```

Alternatively, you could leave the parameter index numbers as they are and use the up/down arrows on the Parameters tab of the tools Properties to move the parameter order on the tool dialog to match that of your code.